# Why does my MySQL MATCH() AGAINST() query fail with columns from LEFT JOIN'd databases?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, left-join

I've got a MySQL query somewhat like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN descriptions ON products.DescriptionID = descriptions.ID 
WHERE MATCH (name, overview, specs) AGAINST ('ram');
```

All columns I'm trying to search with `MATCH() AGAINST()` are FULLTEXT, but I get the following error when testing in phpMyAdmin:

```
#1210 - Incorrect arguments to MATCH
```

If I only `MATCH` one column it doesn't error and works correctly, but as soon as I try to `MATCH` multiple columns it fails with this error. I'm running MySQL 5.0.45 and the [MySQL 5.0 Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) documentation implies I can do this.

Is it because of the `LEFT JOIN`? Do I need to `OR` together a bunch of `MATCH() AGAINST()` function calls?

**Update @Zak:** I can't post the table creation statements, but I can say that in this example the columns are as follows: `products.name`, `descriptions.overview`, `descriptions.specs`. If I specify them in full `table.column` format, it doesn't change the behavior.

However, if I lose `products.name` from the `MATCH()` I get the following error:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

But, both `descriptions.overview` and `descriptions.specs` are FULLTEXT.

Comment: Please post your table creation statements for more complete info.. what columns are in what tables is the first thing to see.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The arguments to `MATCH()` must be the same columns in your FULLTEXT index definition.  They must be the same in number as well as position.

Also, since you can't make an index with multiple columns from different tables, you can't match against columns from different tables in a single `MATCH()` call.

If you want to search text columns from different tables, you'll have to create a FULLTEXT index in each table, and then search each index with a separate `MATCH()` call.  Use `OR` expressions to combine the results.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "They must be the same in number as well as position." I was afraid I'd have to `OR` together a number of `MATCH()` calls.

Comment: I mean if you create an index over three columns, you must list all three columns in the `MATCH()` call, in the same order you defined them in the index.  You can't search just one or two of these columns, and you can't change their order.

Comment: Okay, now I understand and that solved the remaining "Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list" error. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I've run into that same problem. The thing is that you can't match columns from different tables so you have to split the query.

Try something like this (edited to match columns and tables):

```
SELECT p.name, d.overview, d.specs
FROM products AS p 
LEFT JOIN descriptions AS d ON p.DescriptionID = d.ID 
WHERE MATCH (p.name) AGAINST ('ram')
OR MATCH (d.overview, d.specs) AGAINST ('ram');
```

Hope it helps!